# jQuery moving element to sibling not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying detach and prepend an element to a sibling element and nothing is happening, I'm not getting any errors in the console either.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="wp-posts-carousel-container">
    <div class="wp-posts-carousel-image"><a href=" /?event=7-nights-450-2"
                                            title="Read more 7 Nights - £450"><img alt="7 Nights - £450"
                                                                                   style="max-width:100%;max-height:100%"
                                                                                   src=" /wp-content/uploads/2016/10/5e87ac4c-5a68-4206-bebc-51163a92a204-150x150.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="wp-posts-carousel-details"><h3 class="wp-posts-carousel-title"><a
            href=" /?event=7-nights-450-2" title="7 Nights - £450">7 Nights - £450</a></h3>
        <div class="wp-posts-carousel-desc"><span class="event-date-visit" style="font-size: 10pt;"><strong>16th Feb&nbsp;to 23rd Feb&nbsp;2017</strong></span>

            <ul class="chevrons icon ">
                <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i><i class="icon icon-envelope-alt"></i> 4* Hotel</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i><i class="icon icon-film"></i> Daily breakfast &amp; dinner buffet</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i><i class="icon icon-envelope-alt"></i> All ground transfers</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i><i class="icon icon-film"></i> Guided tours to many historical sites</li>
            </ul>

            Flights not included - approx £200
        </div>
        <p class="wp-posts-carousel-buttons"><a href="/contact"
                                                class="wp-posts-carousel-more-button button btn btn-primary"
                                                title="Read more 7 Nights - £450">Enquire Now</a></p>
        <p></p></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(".event-date-visit").each(function() {
      $(this).detach().prependTo($(this).closest('.wp-posts-carousel-image')); 
 });
```

This does nothing at all, anyone know whats happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this, for example:

```
$(".event-date-visit").each(function() {

      $(this).prependTo($(this).parent().parent().prev()); 
 });
```

Do not use detach(), because you will loose $(this).

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ckddg70w/1/

Comment: This one worked for me, none of the other answers worked.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 $(".event-date-visit").each(function() {
  $(this).detach().prependTo($(this).closest('.wp-posts-carousel-image')); 
 });
```

Is not true. Because closest is works when **.wp-posts-carousel-image** is the parent of

**$(".event-date-visit")**

Instead you can do this:

```
 $(".event-date-visit").each(function() {
   $(this).detach().prependTo($(this).closest('.wp-posts-carousel-details').prev()); 
 });
```

Comment: Yeah okay that's the problem but what's the solution?

Comment: That still doesn't do anything.